# JAXB don't marshal cyclic references

Tags: java, jaxb

I have used JAXB before to generate json from a cyclic datastructure and I think I did the same this time, but appearently not, because I get this error:

```
Jul 30, 2018 4:28:08 PM org.eclipse.yasson.internal.Marshaller marshall
SEVERE: Generating incomplete JSON
Jul 30, 2018 4:28:08 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jersey-servlet] in context with path [/Kanzan] threw exception [org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException: java.lang.StackOverflowError] with root cause
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$BaseIterator.<init>(ConcurrentHashMap.java:3389)
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$ValueIterator.<init>(ConcurrentHashMap.java:3430)
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$ValuesView.iterator(ConcurrentHashMap.java:4683)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.ComponentMatcher.searchComponentBinding(ComponentMatcher.java:179)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.ComponentMatcher.getSerializerBinding(ComponentMatcher.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.SerializerBuilder.build(SerializerBuilder.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.ObjectSerializer.marshallProperty(ObjectSerializer.java:91)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.ObjectSerializer.serializeInternal(ObjectSerializer.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.AbstractContainerSerializer.serialize(AbstractContainerSerializer.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.AbstractContainerSerializer.serializerCaptor(AbstractContainerSerializer.java:91)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.ObjectSerializer.marshallProperty(ObjectSerializer.java:92)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.ObjectSerializer.serializeInternal(ObjectSerializer.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.AbstractContainerSerializer.serialize(AbstractContainerSerializer.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.AbstractContainerSerializer.serializerCaptor(AbstractContainerSerializer.java:91)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.ObjectSerializer.marshallProperty(ObjectSerializer.java:92)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.ObjectSerializer.serializeInternal(ObjectSerializer.java:59)
```

This is the source:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@Entity
@Table(name="INTERVIEW")
public class Interview {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column (name = "ID")
    private int id;
    @Column (name="DATE")
    private Date date_;
    @Column (name="TITLE")
    private String title;
    @Column (name="CEO")
    private String ceo;
    @OneToMany (mappedBy="interview", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<QA> QAs;
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="STOCK_ID")
    @XmlTransient
    private Stock stock;

    ....GETTERS and SETTERS...
}


@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@Entity
@Table(name="STOCK")
public class Stock {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column (name = "ID")
    private int id;
    @Column (name="TITLE")
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "stock")
    private Interview interview;

    ....GETTERS AND SETTERS....
}
```

I can marshal if I remove Interview and Stock references from respective..

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED. Some jersey jars where required for the job

Comment: What jersey jars were required??

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why OP wouldn't share the jars, but at least this error message

```
org.eclipse.yasson.internal.Marshaller marshall
SEVERE: Generating incomplete JSON
```

was resolved for me with the following dependencies.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse</groupId>
    <artifactId>yasson</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.json</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.2</version>
</dependency>
```